# How to put the Grafana time range into an ElasticSearch log link?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, grafana, grafana-variable

I'm adding a Data Link or Panel Link to my Grafana panel or data.  I want the link to go to ElasticSearch logs... but I want to include the current time range of my Grafana dashboard.

Here's a portion of a sample Elastic link, relevant part bolded:

> https://myhostname.com/app/discover#/?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-1h,to:now))&_a=

How would I change the **time** section using Grafana variables?

Comment: Nothing in fact is bolded. Consider using code block instead of citation, and marking important parts with ^.

Answer (score 1):

Solve this by replacing the `from` and `to` sections of the Elastic URL with the `__from` and `__to` Grafana variables, as follows:

> [https://myhostname.com/app/discover#/?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:'${__from:date:iso}',to:'${__to:date:iso}'))&_a=](https://myhostname.com/app/discover#/?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:%27$%7B__from:date:iso%7D%27,to:%27$%7B__to:date:iso%7D%27))&_a=)

This results in a URL like this:

> [https://myhostname.com/app/discover#/?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:'2023-07-12T14:38:09.298Z',to:'2023-07-12T17:38:09.298Z'))&_a=](https://myhostname.com/app/discover#/?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:%272023-07-12T14:38:09.298Z%27,to:%272023-07-12T17:38:09.298Z%27))&_a=)

Note two important points:

1. We wrap the variables in quotes (`'`), since we're formatting them as time strings rather than numeric epoch-seconds or epoch-millis
2. We use the `:iso` modifier to force the format.

Can Elasticsearch accept epoch-seconds or millis in its link? Maybe. I'm not sure... but that would be another way to go.

See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-data-links/#time-range-panel-variables for more info.